# how to display individual values?

Tags: php

I get this from `print_r($data)`:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
      [cto_office_id] => 1
      [office_name] => Airtel India
      [address_line1] => Bendoor well
      [phone_office1] => 12345678912
      [phone_office2] => 789451234512
      [address_line2] => Kankanady Circle
      [city] => Mangluru
      [state] => Haryana
      [pin_code] => 002
      [country] => India
      [web_url] => airte.co.in
      [office_quote] => Office
      [date_registered] => 2011-11-24 05:59:51
      [bill_mail_id] => 15612561
      [bill_mail_id_type] =>
      [acc_status] => enabled
      [comments] =>
      [is_account_deleted] => 0
      [account_deleted_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )
  )
)
```

I tried this `$data['phone_office1']`, but that does not work.

Comment: Can you do yourself and us a favor? `echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";` then edit your question with the output. Personally, I have a print_helper with a function called p() that does this automatically. Suggest you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object that is nested inside two arrays. You can get it out like this:

```
$data[0][0]->phone_office1
```